# How to turn a background image effect to CSS

Tags: css, css-gradients

I'm trying to achieve the two effects you see below in CSS, but I can't find how to do them.

Does anyone know the name of this CSS effect or how to achieve something similar with pure CSS?

[image]

Comment: Possibly [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur). Or you might just use an image. What are the desired characteristics of the effect?

Comment: @showdev I would like the same effect as with the purple effect that can be seen on the top right and bottom left. 

I'm trying to avoid using an image for performance

Comment: While I appreciate that you may not know the name of the "effect" you're looking for, do you have anything - HTML, any CSS at all - that might make it easier for us to offer potential solutions? The obvious answer is, I suspect, to use [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/radial-gradient) as a `background-image` on whatever element features the displayed background.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to achieve this using a simple gradient with the outermost color matching the background color at the 100% marker or fading it out completely toward the end with the same color all the way through. Below is an example of the last bit.

```
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63,94,251,1) 0%, rgba(63,94,251,0) 100%);
```